# UILabel update text with fading in functionality

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UILabel which updates every 3 seconds. The index is saved in user defaults. The next quote updates with no problem, however I cannot get it to fadeIn() like it does when I first load the view.

```
       func changeLabelWithTimeInterval(){
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateCounting), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@objc func updateCounting(){
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.integer(forKey: "savedIndexKey")

    let currentIndex = defaults.integer(forKey: "savedIndexKey")
    var nextIndex = currentIndex+1

    nextIndex = quotes.indices.contains(nextIndex) ? nextIndex : 0
    defaults.set(nextIndex, forKey: "savedIndexKey")
    let savedInteger = defaults.integer(forKey: "savedIndexKey")
    saved = savedInteger


    quotesLabel.text = quotes[savedInteger]
    self.quotesLabel.fadeIn()



}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    changeLabelWithTimeInterval()
     self.quotesLabel.fadeIn()
    }

  extension UIView {
    func fadeIn(duration: TimeInterval = 5.0, delay: TimeInterval = 0.0, completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void) = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1.0
        }, completion: completion)
    }

    func fadeOut(duration: TimeInterval = 3.0, delay: TimeInterval = 1.0, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = {(finished: Bool) -> Void in}) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: delay, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.alpha = 0.0
        }, completion: completion)
    }
}
```

Comment: try UIView.transition with View method and set label text inside animation block with animation option as `.transitionCrossDissolve`. So you can forgot about alpha setting

Answer (score 0):

I just used this extension instead. It looks a lot cleaner with this.

```
extension UIView {
func fadeTransition(_ duration:CFTimeInterval) {
    let animation = CATransition()
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name:
        CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
    animation.type = CATransitionType.fade
    animation.duration = duration
    layer.add(animation, forKey: CATransitionType.fade.rawValue)
}
}
```